# mongodb вывод данных по _id

Tags: php, mongodb, вывод

```
 <?php
$m = new MongoClient(); // соединение
$db = $m->news; // получаем базу данных "news" 
$collection = 'new';

/*извлекаем все элементы коллекции*/

$cursor =$db->$collection->find( { _id: 5 } );

/* обходим массив - подразумевается,
что поля действительно определены
ранее при добавлении элементов
*/

echo $cursor->count() . ' document(s) found. <br/>';

foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
echo 'Id: ' . $obj['_id'] . '<br/>';
echo 'Date: ' . $obj['Date'] . '<br/>';
echo 'News: ' . $obj['News'] . '<br/>';
echo '<br/>';
}

?>
```

Здравствуйте, написал скрипт для вывода новостей с базы данных. Пример работы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить его, чтобы при запросе, например `/nosql.php?=1` выводилась только 1 новость? Я могу сделать только добавив цикл в поиск, если `$obj['_id'] =` нужному числу, то вывести дальше. Но это не рационально.

Comment: `find( { _id: 5 } )` [Док](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: Только что нашел  эту функцию, а как вывести результат на экран? db.new.find( { _id: 5 } )

Comment: `$collection->find({ _id: 5 })->toArray();` как вариант, можете и проверять, если не массив...

Comment: Посмотрите, дописал условие в 6-ой строчке в скрипте, теперь ничего не работает, но если брать find( ) ; с пустыми скобками, то выводит все новости

Comment: Так записан `find( ["_id" => 5 ] ) ` для возврата в `PHP`. Это для Монго `find({ _id: 5 })`

Comment: @see [findOne](http://php.net/manual/ru/mongocollection.findone.php)

Comment: Из всех методов сработал вот такой $ids = array('_id' => 1);

$cursor =$db->$collection->find($ids);